# How do I display a 'Please Wait' message in javascript when the mainframe language RPGILE is slow to respond?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, but must make a mod to a slow running RPGILE program (mainframe language).  I tried the below code, but the form doesn't submit until I respond to the alert box.

```
    <input type="submit" name="Continue" value="Send this order " onClick="alert('Please Wait...')" >
```

Answer (score 0):

An alert box will pause everything else until it's dismissed.

As a quick alternative, you could hide the button on click and show the 'Please wait...' message in its place.

Try replacing your input with this:

```
<div>
    <input type="submit" name="Continue" id="sendButton" value="Send this order">
    <div id="loadingMessage" style="display: none;">Please wait...</div>
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('sendButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.getElementById('sendButton').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('loadingMessage').style.display = 'block'
    });
</script>
```